# Why is my JavaScript Magic SDK front end integration unable to confirm transactions?

Tags: harmony, magic-sdk

Magic RPC Error, unable to confirm transaction after 20 attempts

Two months ago, I wrote some JavaScript code for a front end integration of the Magic SDK to the Harmony testnet. I was able to send a transaction to a smart contract with the sendTransaction function.

However, I came back to the code today and found that I was unable to replicate what I did on the Harmony Mainnet. For whatever reason, the RPC is unable to confirm any transactions that I send through.

I can confirm that the RPC itself is working, because I am able to send transactions to the same smart contract on the Harmony Mainnet. I can also confirm that the gasLimit (1 million) and gasPrice (5000 gwei) are way above what is necessary, and that I have enough funds in the Magic wallet for the transaction.

I appreciate any help I can get on this, thanks in advance.

Below is an excerpt of the Magic implementation

```
const tx = await deployedContract.methods.addBid(
    props.smartContractPayload.numBids,
    props.smartContractPayload.numCT,
    props.smartContractPayload.insuranceChoice
  );

  let { txPayload } = tx.transaction;

  txPayload.from = props.smartContractPayload.selectedAccount;
  txPayload.gasLimit = "1000000";

  const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
  
  txPayload.gasPrice = String(
    Number(ethers.utils.formatEther(gasPrice)) * 1000000000000000000 * 5
  );



  const txSend = await props.smartContractPayload.magic.harmony.sendTransaction(
    txPayload
  );

  const txReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(
    txSend.transactionHash
  );
```